# Filter out multiple emojis from Unicode text in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, emoji

Let's say we have following strings containing emojis:

```
sent1 = '  right'
sent2 = 'Some text?! '
sent3 = ''
```

The task is to remove text and get the following output:

```
sent1_emojis = '  '
sent2_emojis = ' '
sent3_emojis = ''
```

Based on past question ([Regex Emoji Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48945826/8201676)) I use the following regex to identify strings that contain at least one emoji:

```
emoji_pattern = re.compile(u".*(["
u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                "])+", flags= re.UNICODE)
```

In order to get the output string I use the following:

```
re.match(emoji_pattern, sent1).group(0)
```

and so on.

There's a problem with the `sent2` string. `re.match(emoji_pattern, sent1).group(0)` returns the whole `sent2` instead of emojis only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little change in `emoji_pattern` will do the job:

```
emoji_pattern = re.compile(u"(["                     # .* removed
u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                "])", flags= re.UNICODE)             # + removed

for sent in [sent1, sent2, sent3]:
    print(''.join(re.findall(emoji_pattern, sent)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rmove text, you can do it without worrying about emojis, just use pattern that will match any character, like `\w`, which will match any word character (equivalent for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). If you need to match more, eg. whitespaces, use `[\w\s]`. If you need dots, commas, etc. use `[\w\s\.,-]`. Then replace any match with empty string.

This way you'll remove anything except emojis.

EDIT: I got interesting result in Python regex engine: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW87lM/1)

I used `[\u0000-\uFFFF]`, which should match ANY character. Suprisignly, it doesn't match emojis, while `.` (dot, meaning any character) does match emojis.